# How to decode MP3 files? How MP3 files stores sounds?

Tags: mp3

I'm not talking about any concrete language here. I want to analyse the MP3 file, so I want to get some information about sound from specific second (i don't know, tone/height/frequency of sound). How those data is stored in single file?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have weeks (months?) available to play with it, I would recommend using an existing MP3 decoding library to pull the decoded audio out of the file.  In C/C++, there's libMAD or libmpg123, as well as the Windows components.  In C#, you can use [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) or [NLayer](http://nlayer.codeplex.com/).

Once you have the decoded data, you'll need to run a [FFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform), [DFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform), or [DCT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform) over it to convert to frequency & amplitude.  The FFT is probably your best bet, though the DFT may give a less "noisy" analysis.  YMMV.

Note that all three of the transforms provide amplitude values you can convert to decibel values.

Answer (score 0):

there are some useful MP3 Librarys where you get information about your MP3 file.

If you use C# it could be NAudio.
http://naudio.codeplex.com/

Answer (score -2):

I recommend the program xxd and google for the first steps.

First of all i would look into its binary code.

```
xxd -b file.mp3
```

Viewing it as ASCII also exposes some information.

```
xxd file.mp3
```

That was my first steps.